# Comments in Qt qrc file

Tags: qt, resources

How to add comments to Qt qrc file?
I tried // and /* */, but this gives me an error "RCC Parse error ... [unexpected text]".
Sample file:

```
<RCC>
<qresource>
    // images
    <file>image1.png</file>
    <file>image2.png</file>

    // qml documents
    <file>doc1.qml</file>
    <file>doc2.qml</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A format of .qrc files is based on XML. Therefore you can use XML-style for comments:

```
    Comment    ::=      '<!--' ((Char - '-') | ('-' (Char - '-')))* '-->'
```

An example of a comment:

```
<!-- declarations for <head> & <body> -->
```

[XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-comments)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `<!-- -->`
e.g.

```
<!-- this is my comment in qrc file -->
```